# Java String objects storage

Tags: java, string

```
String str=new String ("Hello");
str=str.substring(1,3);
System.out.println(str);
```

Result: `el`

In the above code, After first line executes a new string object create in heap. In the second line where is the string object (str) get create. In **heap or string literal pool**?

Comment: Considering it's not a string literal, the heap.

Comment: unless you call `intern()` on it then it's the heap

Answer (score -1):

In heap of course. The string goes to string literal pool only if we create String by "" (double quotes).

Comment: "only" you sure? (There is another way strings can be added to the pool)

Comment: Hmmm, you talk about intern() method?